# binarySearch in int array does not find properly value 0 and less

Tags: java

I have performed following tests:

```
int[] test1 = {1, 2, 3};
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(test1, 3)); //prints 2

int[] test2 = {1, 0, 3};
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(test2, 0)); //prints 1

int[] test3 = {1, 2, 0};
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(test3, 0)); //prints -1 (item not found), expected value: 2
```

I just found bug in Java implementation or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Read the JavaDoc before making call to an api! From binarySearch javaDoc: The array must be sorted (as by the {@link #sort(long[])} method) prior to making this call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Binary search expects input sequence to be sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(byte[],%20byte)) (as by the sort(byte[]) method).

That's why only this one returns correct result:

```
int[] test1 = {1, 2, 3};  // <-- this has to be sorted.
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(test1, 3)); //prints 2
```

So, you didn't find a bug in java :) If you pass unsorted array to binary search then it will not return correct results. For unsorted arrays you have to use sequential search.

Comment: Yeah. That's the point...